# How to emulate "Keep local version" of SourceSafe

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

I am not sure if this can be done and how to properly do this (if possible)

I have a Visual studio 2012 Project connected to TFS 2012.

I'd like to replicate the "keep local version" option of the old SourceSafe:

- get an item for edit
- modify it locally
- release the lock on the item, **keeping my local version** (in SourceSafe it was "undo checkout + keep local version);
- (later) compare my local version with the server version (maybe edited by someone else) and merge if needed.

Example: get the latest .config (pointing to production environment) edit it locally to point to test environment and prevent any kind of lock so that other team members could edit and check in the .config if needed.

If this can be done on TFS, which is the suggested procedure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you do not have TFS configured to lock files...(I think it's possible but never used it) just edit your local file and exclude it from your pending changes so it's not including in any future commits. You can include it later and merge it.

Comment: It works, but in TFS the file status is still checked out (even if others can edit it). Is it possible to keep the local edit AND have the status "not in editing" in TFS? I know that there are 2 distinct kind of check out to manage this situation but we would like a more "source safe like" workflow.

Comment: Switch to a local workspace rather than a server one...tye server then never gets told about checked out files..

Comment: @Luca VSS is a **terrible**, antiquated VCS. Rather than trying to emulate workflows forced upon you by poor tooling, I'd recommend embracing the features of the tools you're using now and creating new workflows.

Comment: I agree with @DanielMann (I never really liked VSS even in Visual Basic 6 era) and I'll propose to the team MrHinsh and dotjoe solution.